# What does the SQL Server XML datatype translate to in .NET and how do I convert it to XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

We have a column in the database that has a type of `xml`. I am reading this information via the .net `SqlDataReader`, but I'm not sure what to cast it to.

The msdn table (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx) suggests that is of the .net type `Xml`, but there is no `System.Xml`, only `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml` so I'm not sure if that is correct.

So my question is this:

What do I cast the `SqlDbType.Xml` to as I'm reading it from a `SqlDataReader`, and how do I convert that to `XmlDocument`?

Comment: are you using SqlConnection or Entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember casting it to a string. Feeding XmlDocument with a string works as usual then.

Comment: While that works, I think it's better to work with the native type instead.

Comment: What justifies this judgement? Better in what sense? Easier, faster, ...?

Comment: Well it's type-safe to start with if you care about that sort of things. I'd expect it to be faster too because the XmlReader could work with the stream directly and would not necessarily have to load everything into a string first.

Comment: Casting to string is also type safe, it would not cast otherwise. I wonder about performance, however.

Comment: While each XML value is a string, not every string is XML, wouldn't you agree with that? As for performance, I've had a look into the System.Data code and updated the answer for you.

Comment: Also be aware that [the string may be truncated](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310378)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: That's true but only for "for xml" queries, whereas in the case of the OP, he's using a column of type xml and the bug doesn't exist in that case.  Thanks for mentioning it though.

Answer (score 29):

It translates to [`SqlXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx) and you can get an `XmlReader` with [`SqlXml.CreateReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.createreader.aspx)from it. You'd have to use  [`SqlDataReader.GetSqlXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlxml.aspx)method to get the type instead of a string.

For example:

```
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SqlXml xmlData =
            reader.GetSqlXml(0);
            XmlReader xmlReader = xmlData.CreateReader();

            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    string elementName = xmlReader.LocalName;
                    xmlReader.Read();
                    Console.WriteLine(elementName + ": " + xmlReader.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:** To answer a helpful comment from @Wiktor Zychla

The performance of this approach is better and can be *a lot* better when dealing with large XML fields because `SqlReader.GetString` will load the field content into a string first while `SqlReader.GetSqlXml` creates an XmlReader from the stream directly. That can be quickly verified with a look at System.Data in Reflector or a similar tool.

Answer (score 4):

I use this method myself, using `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();`

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
{
    XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        xdoc.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that would only work for "a single-row, single-column result set that contains XML data", to quote MSDN.

Comment: As i guess 'XmlDocument' Variable does not take 'Xmlreader' as an object for function Load().

Comment: @A CRM - it does now.   using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = xmlData.CreateReader())
            {
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                xd.Load(xmlReader);
                return xd;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's a [System.Xml namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The System.Xml namespace provides standards-based support for processing XML.

To use it, though, you'll probably have to add it as a reference in your project. Microsoft has [instructions for doing this in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

Comment: Not relevant to the answer.