# Format XML Returned from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a program that I have written in Visual Studio. Here is the code:

```
namespace SQL_Connectivity
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=************.database.windows.net,0000;Database=testdb;User ID=testuser;Password= testpassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;");
        conn.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM District WHERE leaID <= 4 FOR XML PATH('districtEntry'), ROOT('districts')", conn);
           SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           string path = @"District." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml";
           var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
           while(reader.Read())
           {
               Console.SetOut(writer);
               Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));

           }

           reader.Close();
           conn.Close();
       }
   }
}
```

Assume that the SqlConnection string is valid. The query goes on to query the database and return the results in perfect format. However, when it goes through my code, it gets saved in a XML file which looks like this:

```
<districts><districtEntry><leaID>01</leaID><name>Alachua</name>    <organizationType>LEA</organizationType><streetLine1>620 E University     Ave</streetLine1><city>Gainesville</city><stateProvince>FL</stateProvince><postalCode>326015448</postalCode><county>Alachua</county><NCESID_district>1200030</NCESID_district><date_created>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_created><date_updated>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_updated></districtEntry><districtEntry><leaID>02</leaID><name>Baker</name><organizationType>LEA</organizationType><streetLine1>270 South Blvd E</streetLine1><city>MacClenny</city><stateProvince>FL</stateProvince><postalCode>320632538</postalCode><county>Baker</county><NCESID_district>1200060</NCESID_district><date_created>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_created><date_updated>2015-06-01T20:38:58.9730000</date_updated></districtEntry><districtEntry><leaID>03</leaID><name>Bay</name><organizationType>LEA</organizationType><streetLine1>1311 Balboa Ave</streetLine1><city>Panama City</city><stateProvince>FL</st
```

It all ends up on one row, AND my code does not finish the XML file (missing data at the end). It seems to always stop at the row before the last in the table. I have also tried this with multiple tables.

I am asking if there is a way to

1. Format my XML file to make it nice & neat on separate lines.
2. Adjust my code so that the results from the query are saved exactly how it is into the XML file.

Comment: Does reader.Getstring(0) return the right result in the debugpreview at runtime

Comment: That's not even VB syntax, it's C#!

Comment: @har07 Yeah sorry, I meant to say that I was using Visual Studio to write C#. It was a long day.

Comment: @BrandonLumsden no problem, as long as you clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solves several of the problems with your original code and your answer:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (
        var conn =
            new SqlConnection(
                "Server=************.database.windows.net,0000;Database=testdb;User ID=testuser;Password= testpassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")
        )
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (
            var cmd =
                new SqlCommand(
                    "SELECT * FROM District WHERE leaID <= 4 FOR XML PATH('districtEntry'), ROOT('districts')",
                    conn))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                string path = @"District." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml";
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    doc.Save(writer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First, the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `XmlReader` and `StreamWriter` all need to be in `using` blocks, in order to ensure that they are cleaned up, even if an exception is thrown.

Second, `DataSet` cannot process all possible XML documents. It can only process those which could be represented as "relational" tables. It is also unnecessary overhead to build out tables and columns when all you want to do is parse XML. I use `XDocument` instead.

Finally, the `XDocument.Save` method writes out the XML with indentation.

Comment: so are the using statements functioning like try...catch in Visual Basic? Thank you for the explanation.  Also, are you saying that the Xml that the query produces will change at some point & hence become unreadable by the dataset?

Comment: Using statements are like `Try ... Finally x.Dispose() End Try`. They ensure that `Dispose` is called on the value in the expression in the clause.

Comment: Oh okay, so `Dispose()` is doing the work of the `reader.Close()` & `conn.Close()` that was in my code initially. The using statements call `Dispose()` on it's own without me having to call the close method. At least this is what i'm gathering from your post. Very informative!

Comment: See [`IDisposable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use reader.GetSqlXml to get the result.
Take a look at 
[What does the SQL Server XML datatype translate to in .NET and how do I convert it to XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690991/what-does-the-sql-server-xml-datatype-translate-to-in-net-and-how-do-i-convert)

Comment: So I would do :

        `SqlXml xmlData =
         reader.GetSqlXml(0);`



        `Console.WriteLine(xmlData);`

or would it be something different?

Comment: I tried using all suggestions in that link and nothing has worked. 

I keep getting an error on this line

`SqlXml xmldata = reader.GetSqlXml(0);`

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCachedBuffer'.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a solution & here is the code that I changed it to:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM District FOR XML PATH('districtEntry'), ROOT('districts')", conn);
        string path = @"District." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml";
        XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
        var data = new DataSet();
        data.ReadXml(reader);
        data.WriteXml(path);
```

I learned that the `reader.Read()` was reading the file line by line and writing it to the file.

Comment: This is not a good solution in the general case. DataSet.ReadXml cannot read every XML document.