# How to store the XML file returned from SQL Server during selection statement in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, stored-procedures

During fetching of data in C#, how can we store the XML file returned from a SQL Server stored procedure into a `string` or `var`?

My code:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, ListParam.ToArray());
```

My query is

```
select * 
from table_Name 
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('Collection');
```

Comment: Please Go through this `link` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604603/format-xml-returned-from-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited as per the OP's request.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, ListParam.ToArray()))
{
    if (reader == null) return;     
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadOuterXml());
    }
    string xmlVal = sb.ToString(); // You can get the xml as string here. 
}
```

Comment: from storedProcedure the datas are return as XML file. agin i need to convert to Xml i need to make only the retuened xml to stored in a var or in a string as XML

Comment: After saving, read a file like this :string myXml = File.ReadAllText("test.xml");

Comment: i didn't get u?

Comment: again ur using the sqlcommnd , am using the sqlDataReader to run the storeprocedure

Comment: SqlDataReader rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, ListParam.ToArray());

Comment: use `ExecuteXmlReader` instead of `sqlDataReader`. Since, Execute xml reader provides you the result as `XMLReader`

Comment: Change your code as look like: `var rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteXmlReader(Conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, ListParam.ToArray());`

Comment: This isn't correct, it will overwrite `xmlVal` on each loop leaving you with whatever was last read.