# How to read complete result of FOR XML SQL Server Query?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, sqlcommand

I want to save the complete result of a `FOR XML` SQL Query to a file.

My SQL Query looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customer FOR XML RAW
```

in my code, I now want to execute this query against an SQL Server and read the complete XML result and save it to disk.

My code looks like this:

```cs
using (XmlReader xmlResultReader = command.ExecuteXmlReader()) //command is my SqlCommand
using (MemoryStream resultFile = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(resultFile, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    while (xmlResultReader.Read())
    {
        writer.WriteLine(xmlResultReader.ReadOuterXml());
    }


    //write stream to file
}
```

But when I run this, **not the complete** result of the query gets saved to the `MemoryStream`. The result is **truncated** in the middle of a `<row />` element in the resulting XML. So not even the returned XML is valid.

I also tried writing the result with an `XmlWriter` using this code:

```cs
xmlWriter.WriteNode(xmlResultReader, false);
```

but this showed the same result.

So now my question is: How can I get the complete XML result of the query from the `XmlReader` returned by `ExecuteXmlReader()`?

Comment: Have you tried [How to create an XML file from a XmlReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988832/3744182).  This looks to be a duplicate, as the `XmlReader` in that question is also returned by `SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader()`

Comment: I have tried to do this with the WriteNode method of the XmlWriter. But as I have written above, this will also truncate my xml result.

Comment: In that question they set `CommandTimeout = 60000;`.  Could that be the problem?  [Format XML Returned from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30604603/3744182) also seems very similar.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried setting it to the same value as in the question but nothing changes. The command completes without any exception and the resulting xml is not the complete result that i get in SSMS with this query.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775242