# How to bulk insert rows with some columns of xml type into the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I'm trying to bulk insert rows into the database. Some of the columns of this table are of XML type and that's where I am facing some issues.

I tried using `SqlBulkCopy` to achieve this but keep on getting the error that XElement cannot be converted to a string although I'm never doing a type cast.

This is my table design:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TasksQueue]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessData] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [MetaData] [xml] NULL,
    [SubmittedBy] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ResultData] [xml] NULL,
    [SubmittedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProcessedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProcessingTime] [varchar](28) NULL,
    [DistrictID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TasksQueue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

My code in C#:

```
public static void CreateBulkTasks(List<Task> BulkTasks)
{
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsKeys.QwizdomOnlineDBConnectionString];
        _obj = new object();

        lock (_obj)
        {
            DataTable tableMember = new DataTable();
            DataTable tableLicense = new DataTable();

            var x = BulkTasks[0].MetaData;

            tableMember.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(Int32));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("ProcessData", typeof(XElement));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("MetaData", typeof(XElement));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("SubmittedBy", typeof(Int32));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(Int32));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("ResultData", typeof(XElement));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("SubmittedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("ProcessedDate", typeof(DateTime));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("ProcessingTime", typeof(string));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("DistrictID", typeof(Int32));
            tableMember.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            foreach (var task in BulkTasks)
            {
                tableMember.Rows.Add(
                    task.Type,
                    task.ProcessData,
                    task.MetaData,
                    task.SubmittedBy,
                    task.Status,
                    task.ResultData,
                    task.SubmittedDate,
                    task.ProcessedDate,
                    task.ProcessingTime,
                    task.DistrictID,
                    task.Name
                );
            }

            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulkCopyGroupMembers = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
            {
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.DestinationTableName = "[TasksQueue]";
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("Type", "Type");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("ProcessData", "ProcessData");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("MetaData", "MetaData");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("SubmittedBy", "SubmittedBy");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("Status", "Status");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("ResultData", "ResultData");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("SubmittedDate", "SubmittedDate");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("ProcessedDate", "ProcessedDate");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("ProcessingTime", "ProcessingTime");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("DistrictID", "DistrictID");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                bulkCopyGroupMembers.WriteToServer(tableMember);
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public TasksQueueType Type { get; set; }
    public XElement ProcessData { get; set; }
    public XElement MetaData { get; set; }
    public int? SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedByName { get; set; }
    public TasksQueueItemStatus Status { get; set; }
    public XElement ResultData { get; set; }
    public int? DistrictID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProcessedDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? ProcessingTime { get; set; }
    public bool? HighPriority { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I expect the bulk data to be inserted into to table in a single go. Instead I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690991/what-does-the-sql-server-xml-datatype-translate-to-in-net-and-how-do-i-convert

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `XmlDocument` instead of `XElement` in your code. The data type for `ProcessData`, `MetaData` and `ResultData`  should be `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this by serializing the XElement to string and setting the column to string in DataTable. I already had a model created by Linq to SQL, so I prepared a second model with string in place of XElement and bulk copied that.

Comment: The column was still of xml type in the database. BulkCopy seems to have a problem with translating XElement to xml, but not string to xml.